# Anagrams of STRAPAZZATA ending with A, and also starting and ending with A

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, proof-explanation

In the word we have:
1S 1P 1R 2T 2Z 4A

For the first "ending with A"
Let's give it a fixed position so let's calculate the anagrams of SPRTTZZAAA

$$\dfrac {10!}{2!2!3!} = 151 200$$

Similarly for starting and ending with $``A"$

$$\dfrac {9!}{2!2!2!} = 45 360$$

I took this exercise form a book which has also it's solutions. But I really do not agree with their solution to this problem because it's contradictory. What do you think of mine? is it valid?

In my manual:

They find $\frac {10!}{3!2!2!}=151200$
Which are the anagram with ending "A"

Total anagrams $\frac{11!}{4!2!2!}=415800$

And say that the anagrams ending with "A" are $415800-151200=264600$ (First problem)

Then calculate the anagrams not ending with A which are
$415800 - 151200 = 264600$

And finally they define the ensemble *S* and *E* for Starting with "A" and Ending with "A"

Then $S \cap E$ is what I got, $45360$
But they calculate after $S\cup E = |S|+|E|-|S\cap E|= 257040$

Therefore the one starting and ending with "A" are $|\Omega|-|S\cup E|$
(Second Problem)

Is therefore the correction wrong?

Comment: Your work looks fine but that begs the question, what is theirs?

Comment: @H. sapiensrex  there it is, the manual correction, what do you think ?

Comment: Also for @DumperDGrab

Comment: The manual's solutions are indeed wrong.  Its first calculation is for anagrams not ending with A.  Its second calculation does not make sense.